# animating a model without redrawing the whole background drawing --OPENGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

Using OPENGL , I am making a simple animation where a small triangle will move through the path that  I have created with mouse (glutMotionFunc).

So the problem is how can I animate a small triangle without redrawing the whole path using glutSwapBuffers();

And also ,how can I rotate that triangle only.

I don't want to use *overlay* as switching between these 2 layers takes much time.

Comment: Redrawing the entire scene is the normal way to do it. For a simple animation and shape, it's not worth going out of your way to avoid redrawing the triangle. As always, avoid premature optimizations. This is a huge premature optimization you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If redrawing the whole path is really too expensive, you can do your rendering to an off-screen framebuffer. The mechanism to do this with OpenGL is called Frame Buffer Object (FBO)

Explaining how to use FBOs in detail is beyond the scope of an answer here, but you should be able to find tutorials. You will be using functions like:

- `glGenFramebuffers()`
- `glBindFramebuffer()`
- `glFramebufferRenderbuffer()` or `glFramebufferTexture()`

This way, you can draw just the additional triangle to your FBO whenever a new triangle is added. To show your rendering on screen, you can copy the current content of the FBO to the primary framebuffer using `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cant! Because it just does not makes sense!

The way computer screen work is the same as in films: fps! Frames per second. There is no thing as "animation" in screens, it is just a fast series of static images, but as our eyes cannot see things moving fast, it looks like it is moving.

This means that every time something changes in the thing you want to draw, you need to create a new "static image" of that stage, and that is done with all the `glVertex` and so pieces of code. Once you finish drawing you want to put it on the screen, so you swap your buffer.